# How to enable/disable a custom control created on the fly (seeing the original control) if parent control is enabled/disabled

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, select, client-side

I have an HTML `<select>` in many places in my application, and I want to replace it with a custom drop down. I have created the custom control which will replace the HTML `<select>` on DOM ready.

Now, I want to implement something that will disable/re-enable my new control if there is a Javascript disabling/enabling the original control without doing any changes in the application elsewhere except within the control.

How is it that I can capture the event of the HTML select control being disabled or enabled and attach some code to that? Is there any other way to do it?

**UPDATE:**
I got this thing working in IE7, Safari/Chrome but its **not working in mozilla**. Sample code in here http://jsfiddle.net/M73Wg/3/

Comment: Can you post some markup/js? Why don't you use events directly on your custom drop down?

Answer (score 0):

This is a tricky one. Unfortunately (I believe) there is no straight answer. It comes down to:  Yes you can do so by using JavaScripts `DOMAttrModified` event listener, but it's not cross-browser compatible.

Here are a few resources that might help you:

- [Detect Attribute Changes with jQuery](http://darcyclarke.me/development/detect-attribute-changes-with-jquery/#) (possible solution)
- [Is it possible to listen for changes to an object's attributes in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/240592/is-it-possible-to-listen-for-changes-to-an-objects-attributes-in-javascript)
- [Listen for changes of checked/disabled in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8267403/listen-for-changes-of-checked-disabled-in-jquery)

Comment: Thanks alot Ayman for giving a good direction, the first link i had seen but wanted some other way out than interval but i guess i'll have to go with it if i want my code to be crossbrowser..

Answer (score 0):

Finally used timeout only http://jsfiddle.net/8EtJK/6/

DOMAttrModified is not working in mozilla

Regards,
SJ